# field ‘ifru_addr’ has incomplete type ‘sockaddr’

Tags: c++11

I am doing the Standford CS144 lab, but the code cannot make

```
In file included from /home/wangyan/csLab/sponge/libsponge/util/tun.cc:7:
/usr/include/linux/if.h:211:19: error: field ‘ifru_addr’ has incomplete type ‘sockaddr’ 
struct sockaddr ifru_addr;
```

I try the others recommend，add the code

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

It still doesn't work

Comment: This bug has been fixed in the kernel in 2017. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/2618be7dccf8739b89e1906b64bd8d551af351e6

Answer (score 5):

Add the

```c
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
```

before the

```c
#include <linux/if.h>
```

in the file `libsponge/util/tun.cc`.

Like this:

```c
#include "tun.hh"
#include "util.hh"

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

...

#include <linux/if.h>

...
```